# How to get non repeating random number pairs,elements can repeat

Tags: java, algorithm, random, game-development

I'm currently programming a  BattleShip game in Java, I randomly generate x, then y for the first cell of the ship,

```
public class Cell implements Comparable<Cell> {


    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    Cell(int xc, int yc) {
        x = xc;
        y = yc;
    }


    public Cell continueWithDirection(Direction d) {
        switch (d) {
            case ROW -> {
                return new Cell(x + 1, y);
            }

            case COLUMN -> {
                return new Cell(x, y + 1);
            }
        }
        ;

        return new Cell(x, y);
    }
}

//file 2

import java.util.Random;

public enum Direction {
    ROW,
    COLUMN;

  private static final Random randomizer=new Random();
  
    static Direction random(){
        boolean b = randomizer.nextBoolean();
        if (b) {
            return Direction.ROW;
        } else {
            return Direction.COLUMN;
        }
    }
}
```

```
Cell[] cells = new Cell[size];
cells[0] = new Cell(randomizer.nextInt(getAreaWidth() - size + 1), randomizer.nextInt(getAreaHeight() - size + 1));

for (int i = 1; i < cells.length; i++) {
    cells[i] = cells[i - 1].continueWithDirection(getDirection());
}

return cells;
```

and then choose a random direction (either up or right) for the other 2 cells of the ship
the first cell is placed from 0 to `bound-shipSize + 1` x and y bound, so I guarantee that all ships will be placed in the border area, but how do I implement random coordinate generation without repeating the same x and y together.  I thought to randomly generate only the first ship, then just randomly go in some direction from the ship and put a new ship, but even so I have to store an array of all ships, and detect collisions.  How can I better implement this algorithm

Comment: Please add some source code for better context.

Comment: What you already tried?

Comment: Have you considered the obvious and simple method of creating a new random position if the one generated was already taken?

Comment: @Kayaman yes, but it is not optimized

Comment: @DiegoBorba to use HashSet

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's not optimized, neither is the rest of your code.

Comment: @Kayaman why? I always felt the opposite.

Comment: You're writing a battleship game where you generate positions rarely. There's no real performance benefits to be had. You're also overengineering this, making a simple issue into a complex.

Comment: Premature optimization is a bad thing. Make it work first!

Comment: Stupid optimization is a bad thing. Unfortunately all programmers go through the same "what if every line were optimized" idea when they start and don't understand what "performance" means, before they get a job and have to provide actual results.

Comment: @Kayaman you are right, I'd better make different logic, but still, I was wondering how it can be optimized

Comment: If you don't want to iterate random tries, then you can keep a list of valid positions. Remove entries from this list as they become invalid. Select a random value from this list.

Comment: @Sam I thought about it, but it is less optimized, in game user can pick cells count, and what if I have 10000000000 cells, and I will place only 3 ships? and in java the ArrayList.remove() is O(n) (because it's backend is the simple array)

Comment: Please provide `Cell` class and the enum class used in `switch(d)`.

Comment: You have to identify your problem first, before you can search for solutions. Even if the generated start positions are unique, it doesn’t guaranty that the ships which extend over multiple cells won’t overlap. Further note that with your current strategy of restricting the start position, certain legal placements are impossible (e.g. a vertical ship close to the right border or a horizontal ship close to the lower border [or upper border when you direction is upward]).

Comment: @user502233: No real battleship game has 10000000000 cells, so you're moving the goal post. One important skill you will need to develop is to find out "what is needed": do I need this code to be able to handle very large number of sparsely populated cells? (then the "try random, repeate if occupied" method works fine) or do I need to do be able to handle "normal battleship dimensions"? Because writing the code that can handle all of these equally well is most certainly wasted effort: it's not needed.

Comment: @JoachimSauer thank you, I am going to make  more flexible design (for follower ideas) and less absolute solution.

Comment: There are a few paths to pick from here. Either you go for a optimistic approach (let's try this box, is it valid?) or a pessimistic approach (keeping track of what valid choices there are). Keeping track of valid choices can either be whitelisting or blacklisting. These options all come with price, and that price varies with size and filling rate. No one size fits all here.

Comment: @Sam, I decide to use the optimistic approach, and make the hasColision method for Cells(no Cell) class then iterate over the collection of Cells(no Cell) and  call hasColision method

Answer (score 0):

I come up with a really good algorithm, but to understand this, you will know the work and feature of LCG. I have NoneRepeatRandomPairs class, and `int[] getPair(int first)` method in it, that class is storing a HashMap with integer key and LCG like Randomizer value in it, when you  request a new random pair giving an int, it gets the neccesery LCG(at your provided key) from HashMap, and return your provided int with new generated, if the LCG's period is passed then the key is changing inner  LCG with other from the same HashMap, and the `int[] getPair(int first)` is giving the redirected integer and another integer genereted by it's LCG